# Power Apps: Item Level Permission Error: document library contains a column that enforces unique values

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I am trying to make my power app have the functionality where only the user using the app can read their own items and edit their own created items.

[image]

Getting error `Cannot change item-level permissions because this list or document library contains a column that enforces unique values.` 
[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I need some columns to be unique records to identify each unique user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no solution to this unless you disable the unique value of those columns.

Comment: Do you know how to disable unique values of columns?

Comment: Column settings > Edit > More options > Set "Enforce unique values" to "No".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like while submitting some column contains duplicate value. Check each unique enforced column value have unique value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).